# Require email registered to be from specific domain(s)

Tags: php, laravel-4

All,

I'm curious what the best approach to this would be. In case the tags weren't noticed, I'm using PHP and Laravel 4.

My application requires that users register with an email address that is from specific domain names. Currently there is only one domain, however, I can see it being a requirement to white list others.

I would assume it would be best to put the domains into an array. Would I run a regex from $rules array against that array? I'm somewhat green to regex. I don't use it often enough to commit anything advanced to memory so feel free to talk to me like a 2 year old.

Comment: Make a list with accepted domains, and compare your input agains't that list. & done

Comment: Create a custom validator for this http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Thanks @JackPoint. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @JackPoint - if you want to put that into an Answer, I'll give you the credit for the link. I should have seen that in the documentation but I think I have code goggles and missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom validator for this. See http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules for reference.